# to run schtasks in windows xp using vb script

Tags: shell, vbscript

i try to run schtasks using vb script. it runs fine when the path name is without space(/TR C:\ABC.exe) but when i give path name as "/TR C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\ABC.exe",i.e with space. the task is not created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes for the path, like you would do it on the command line.

As a VBScript string, this looks like:

```
"/TR ""C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\ABC.exe"""
```

Comment: @ZapSwami: And *what* error? Most people here do not have clairvoyance skills, you know.

Comment: it shows error in the line where i gave the path as u had mentioned above

Comment: @ZapSwami: **What** error? What's the error description?

Comment: i'm new to vb script. i created the application in notepad . when i double click it shows error. suggest me some tool to run vb script